# Accept integers without using scanf

Tags: c, scanf

In C programming I dont want to use scanf method to accept integers.
I just searched on google I got faster method then scanf to accept integers using code which is posted below but **how to accept unsigned long long int using similar method?**

Code for accepting integers : e.g int n=read_int();

```
#define gc getchar_unlocked
int read_int()
{
    char c = gc();
    while (c < '0' || c > '9') 
        c = gc();
    int ret = 0;
    while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
    {
        ret = 10 * ret + c - '0';
        c = gc();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Imitating C library functions is **not** recommended. Use `scanf` or `fgets` + `atol`/`atoi`/`atoll`.

Comment: @cad this does not imitate any c library function I know of!

Comment: It returns `int` . `c` should be `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a very simple modification

```
unsigned long long read_ULL_int()
{
   ...
   unsigned long long ret = 0;
   ...
}
```